# Стоит ли ждать инициализации сервиса?

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-service

К экземпляру сервиса нельзя обращаться сразу после вызова `startService()`, не получив `NPE`, потому что он запускается асинхронно - это я понял. От `NPE` тогда можно отделаться лишь созданием отдельного потока, в котором происходит ожидание полного запуска сервиса. Можно после запуска потока,в котором происходит ожидание, вызвать нужные методы в этом же потоке(методы сервиса, которые вызывались пока был в процессе старта), но если это при каждом старте разные методы или они вызываются несколько раз? Нужна или очередь из этих методов или вообще какой нибудь другой подход.
 Да и поток на такую мелочь - дороговато.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не изобретать велосипед рекомендую посмотреть на рекомендованные Google подходы через использование WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/
Особенно это важно в из-за продолжающегося ужесточения работы сервисов на всех платформах выше Android 6+

Comment: WorkManager рекомендуют чаще для недлительных операций, а целесообразно ним заменить сервисы и реализации потоков для, к примеру проигрывателя музыки или скачивания файлов?